# FFmpeg получить кадр без черных полос

Tags: gd, ffmpeg, php

Есть задача получить определенный кадр из разных видео без черных полос сверху и снизу видео.

Сейчас код выглядит вот так:

```
$movie = new ffmpeg_movie('video.mp4');
$image = $movie->getFrame(25);
$selfimg = $image->toGDImage();
imagepng($selfimg, './screen/'.time().'.png');
imagedestroy($selfimg);
```

Проблема в том, что кадры сохраняются с черными полосами вверху и внизу кадра:

[image]

Можно ли как-то сохранять без этих полос в той же пропорции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опишу алгоритм:

Так как полосы находятся сверху и снизу и известен их цвет, то, по логике, можно использовать команду GD imagecopy, указав координаты от верхней чёрной полосы до нижней.

Вычислить координаты Y для обрезки можно так:

Циклом запускаем проверку, командой imagecolorat, не встречается ли в линии пиксель, отличный от чёрного цвета. Если на линии есть пиксель, отличный от чёрного, значит начался кадр и мы знаем верхнюю координату для обрезки. Таким же способом только идём снизу (с максимальной координаты Y) по снижению значения Y.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ ) уже разобрался.